# Multivariate Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{1},x_{2})=f(x_{1},x_{2})$

then

$F(x_{1},x_{2})=\int^{x_{1}}f(u,x_{2})du+c(x_{2})?$

===============================================

Another question added:

Actually this was what I intended to ask originally.

If

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{1},x_{2})=f(x_{1},x_{2})$,

then

$F(x_{1},x_{2})=\int^{}f(u,x_{2})du+c(x_{2})?$

Am I correct to put the integration constant to depend on $x_{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost right. You have $$F(x_1,x_2)=\int_a^{x_1} f(u,x_2) du + F(a,x_2)$$ for any $a$ with $[a,x_1]\times \{x_2\}$ and in the domain of $F$. If $F(a,x_2)$ is unknown you can right $$F(x_1,x_2)=\int_a^{x_1} f(u,x_2) du + c(x_2)$$ with $F(a,x_2)=c(x_2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added one more question. There is no upper boundary of integration. So it is now indefinite integral. Actually this was what I originally intended to ask. I am especially curious if c, the integration constant, should depend on x_2.